# NPM: Replacing a dependency of a dependency with another build of it

Tags: npm

In one of my projects I use as a dependency in package.json pdfmake, which has in its requires field in package-lock.json pdfkit: "^0.11.0". The problem is that this version of pdfkit has problems with rendering Noto chinese fonts, a problem that was seemingly fixed in pdfkit-next: "0.11.0". What I am trying to do is not to simply update pdfkit, but to change pdfkit to pdfkit-next instead for the pdfmake package, and I couldn't find a way to do it.

Is this possible to do using NPM?

Comment: Perhaps try using the [npm-force-resolutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions) package - I haven't tried it myself, but may be worth trying.